# CRM 2011 Plugin: Entity image: KeyNotFoundException

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I'm developing an update plugin for my custom entity (OpportunityService). My goal is to compare data before and after the update. That's why I have registered an entity image for both Pre image and Post image type. The name of the image is OpportunityService and alias is also OpportunityService.

Then in my code I'm trying to get those images so that I could check if some fields are changed and if they are I would perform some actions. But that's not in the scope of my question.

I'm trying to refer entity images as follows

```
Entity preOpportunityService = (Entity)context.PreEntityImages["OpportunityService"];
Entity postOpportunityService = (Entity)context.PostEntityImages["OpportunityService"];
```

But in that point my plugin throws the System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException.

"Business Process Error. Unexpected exception from plug-in (Execute): OpportunityServicePlugin.OpportunityServiceCalculatorOnUpdate: System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary."

My complete code at the moment is simple as this:

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query;

namespace OpportunityServicePlugin
{
    public class OpportunityServiceCalculatorOnUpdate: IPlugin
    {
        public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {

            // General plugin components 

            IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
            IOrganizationServiceFactory factory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
            IOrganizationService service = factory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);
            ITracingService tracingService = (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));

            try
            {
                // Current opportunity service
                Entity opportunityService = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

                // Opportunity service's parent opportunity lookup reference
                EntityReference opportunityReference = (EntityReference)opportunityService.Attributes["mpc_opportunityid"];

                // Columns to be retrieved for opportunity (aka. columns to be edited)
                ColumnSet opportunityColumnSet = new ColumnSet(new string[] { "estimatedvalue", "mpc_estoneoffinvoicing", "mpc_estinvoicingperyear" });

                // Retrieve actual opportunity entity
                Entity opportunity = service.Retrieve(opportunityReference.LogicalName, opportunityReference.Id, opportunityColumnSet);

                // Opportunity service's money fields
                Money monthlyPrice = (Money)opportunityService["mpc_monthlyprice"];
                Money oneOffPrice = (Money)opportunityService["mpc_startprice"];
                Money estInvoicingPerYear = (Money)opportunityService["mpc_estinvoicingperyear"];

                Entity preOpportunityService = (Entity)context.PreEntityImages["OpportunityService"];
                Entity postOpportunityService = (Entity)context.PostEntityImages["OpportunityService"];

            }
            catch (FaultException<OrganizationServiceFault> ex) { tracingService.Trace("FaultException", ex.ToString()); }
        }
    }
}
```

My plugin is registered at Post operation stage (Update message) synchronously.

What I'm doing wrong here that I can't see?

Thank you in advance.

**Edit: Here's the answer**

Thank you for you answers. By reading them and trying to figure out what's wrong I finally understood that the problem was not with the entity images at all but with this line:

```
EntityReference opportunityReference = (EntityReference)opportunityService.Attributes["mpc_opportunityid"];
```

So because it was Update message and it returns only changed values for the "Target" the "mpc_opportunityid" was the actual problem here -.-

I changed my code to the following

```
try
{
    Entity preOpportunityService = (Entity)context.PreEntityImages["OpportunityService"];
    Entity postOpportunityService = (Entity)context.PostEntityImages["OpportunityService"];

    // Opportunity service's parent opportunity lookup reference
    EntityReference opportunityReference = (EntityReference)postOpportunityService.Attributes["mpc_opportunityid"];

    // Columns to be retrieved for opportunity (aka. columns to be edited)
    ColumnSet opportunityColumnSet = new ColumnSet(new string[] { "estimatedvalue", "mpc_estoneoffinvoicing", "mpc_estinvoicingperyear" });

    // Retrieve actual opportunity entity
    Entity opportunity = service.Retrieve(opportunityReference.LogicalName, opportunityReference.Id, opportunityColumnSet);             

}
catch (FaultException<OrganizationServiceFault> ex) { tracingService.Trace("FaultException", ex.ToString()); }
```

and now it works...

Answer (score 1):

Can you pinpoint on exactly which line do you get this exception?

You could get them where you get images, but also where you get values of mpc_monthlyprice, mpc_startprice and mpc_estinvoicingperyear. When any of them is null, attribute will not be added to opportunityService object, and you'll get exception when trying to retrieve it.

Comment: The problem occurs in this line:

Entity preOpportunityService = (Entity)context.PreEntityImages["OpportunityService"];

I even took those three money fields away from the code, because I can get money values from the image after we've solved this one.

Comment: can you verify if image is correctly registered? i.e. string registredkeys = "Registered pre images:"+String.Join(",", context.PreEntityImages.Keys); and throw exception with this string as error message.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I found the answer. I'm sorry to misleading with my first reply. I added the answer to my original post.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Entity postOpportunityService = (Entity)context.PostEntityImages["OpportunityService"];
```

With the late bound data model in CRM, this statement above will throw the "Key not found" error, if there is no actual value for the "OpportunityService" field in CRM. So this basically means that there is nothing in the field.

You can manually check each of the properties you're trying to fetch for null, or you could just use [crmsvcutil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327844.aspx) and generate your CRM model automatically. This will give you a strongly typed model, and you won't have to worry about the null checks for properties anymore.

Comment: You may have to try to explain it once again for me :) If I create entity images in Plugin registration tool in which kind of case they can be null? I thought that (in this case) whenever I update my OpportunityService entity it will provide me Pre and Post entity images even if the values that I'm asking for have not changed? And I'm getting this same error even if I update all the values I'm fetching...

Comment: are there cases where there are no entity images yet? cases where the "pre" condtion is that no image exists ?

Comment: As far as I know the answer is no because my plugin is registered in Update step / Update message (Post operation).

Answer (score 0):

Use  context.InputParameters["Target"] you get an entity. This entity contains only the attributes that has changed.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but to convert an Entity, like the ones you get from PreEntityImages, PostEntityImages, and InputParameters to a strongly typed class like "opportunity", use the extension method:

```
.ToEntity<opportunity>()
```